# ¿Qué quiere decir "granada" aplicado a la oreja de una vaca?

Tags: vocabulario, animales

Antiguamente, cada ranchero de ganado tenía un símbolo en hierro y un patrón de oreja distintivo, para poder identificar al dueño de cada vaca. En un viejo "Cuaderno de Fierros", hay orejas *rajadas*, con *bocados*, con *puntazos*, y otros términos. Así se explicó la marca de un ranchero:

> Cenal una oreja *rajada* y la hotra ***granada***.

Es fácil imaginar que rajaban las orejas de las vacas con cuchillos, pero **¿qué es *granar* una oreja?** El diccionario de la RAE lo define como "producir y desarrollar el grano." No veo la relación.

<sub>Para ver el resto del texto visite la [Rowland Collection](http://libfmp.ucsc.edu/fmi/iwp/cgi?-db=rowland&-startsession) y busque la tarjeta número 8756; es el documento *ARCHIVES NO. 442*.</sub>

Comment: Me pregunto si tiene que ver con cierta textura.

Answer (score 2):

Posiblemente quiera decir «pintada de [grana](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=JRTVOyU)», que es un tipo de color rojo. De hecho me sorprende bastante que el DLE no incluya una acepción para ese uso.

Esto que describes no es cosa de antiguo solamente. Hoy día sigue siendo bastante habitual que los ganaderos pinten las orejas de algunas de sus reses de distintos colores. Creo que en el texto que referencias, igual que dice "granada" podría decir "morada" o "anaranjada", por ejemplo.

Comment: ¿Pero podría durar el color aplicado durante temporadas enteras? El ganado lleva los padrones aquellos para poder reconocerse meses después.